# Как удалить неактуальные библиотеки (пакеты)

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, anaconda

В папке *\pkgs* скопилось множество пакетов с предыдущими версиями. Например, *pandas-1.0.3*, *pandas-0.25.0*, *pandas-0.24.2*, *pandas-0.23.4*. Три последние это старые версии одного пакета. И так по всем другим обновляемым пакетам. Папка *pkgs* уже занимает 25 ГБ.

Есть какая-нибудь команда, чтобы удалить все НЕактуальные(старые) версии пакетов?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

воспользуйтесь командой `conda clean ...`

```
conda clean -h
usage: conda clean [-h] [-a] [-i] [-p] [-t] [-f] [-c TEMPFILES [TEMPFILES ...]] [-d] [--json] [-q] [-v] [-y]

Remove unused packages and caches.

Options:

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            Show this help message and exit.

Removal Targets:
  -a, --all             Remove index cache, lock files, unused cache packages, and tarballs.
  -i, --index-cache     Remove index cache.
  -p, --packages        Remove unused packages from writable package caches. WARNING: This does not check for packages installed using symlinks back to the package cache.
  -t, --tarballs        Remove cached package tarballs.
  -f, --force-pkgs-dirs
                        Remove *all* writable package caches. This option is not included with the --all flag. WARNING: This will break environments with packages installed using symlinks back to the package cache.
  -c TEMPFILES [TEMPFILES ...], --tempfiles TEMPFILES [TEMPFILES ...]
                        Remove temporary files that could not be deleted earlier due to being in-use. Argument is path(s) to prefix(es) where files should be found and removed.

Output, Prompt, and Flow Control Options:
  -d, --dry-run         Only display what would have been done.
  --json                Report all output as json. Suitable for using conda programmatically.
  -q, --quiet           Do not display progress bar.
  -v, --verbose         Can be used multiple times. Once for INFO, twice for DEBUG, three times for TRACE.
  -y, --yes             Do not ask for confirmation.

Examples:

    conda clean --tarballs
```